# Issue Error Network with Axios on React-native

Tags: react-native, axios

I have this issue "Network Error" on Axios POST method.There's no problem with my api, i tryed this code on a new project and it works fine, i also tryed to Post with the same code on an random api in my current project it works too. My last idea is that the issue comes from a dependency in my project. So if you know something about it.. Thank's a lot for your answer.

here's my package.JSON :

```js
    
    {
    "name": "MyApp",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
      "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .js,.jsx"
     },
     "dependencies": {
    "@eva-design/eva": "2.0.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.13.2",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-native-community/progress-bar-android": "^1.0.4",
    "@react-native-community/progress-view": "^1.2.3",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.8.4",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.12.1",
    "@ui-kitten/components": "5.0.0",
    "@ui-kitten/eva-icons": "5.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.21.0",
    "react": "16.11.0",
    "react-native": "^0.62.2",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.8.0",
    "react-native-pdf": "^6.2.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.1.8",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.12.0",
    "react-native-share": "^4.0.4",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.1.0",
    "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.12.0"
     },
     "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.6.2",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^1.0.0",
    "@ui-kitten/metro-config": "5.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^24.9.0",
    "eslint": "^6.5.1",
    "jest": "^24.9.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.58.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.11.0"
    },
     "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native",
    "transformIgnorePatterns": []
     }
     }
```

and eventually here's my code but as i said it works for other api or an other project with the ccurrent api :

```js
     import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
     import axios from 'axios';$
 
     export default class Webservice {
    static baseUrl = 'https://extranet.mairie-albi.fr:11471/';
    static urlWebservice = this.baseUrl + 'authorisation.php';

    static async request(method, state) {
    const tokenMobile = await AsyncStorage.getItem('tokenMobile');
    const keyConnect = await AsyncStorage.getItem('keyConnect');
    const login = await AsyncStorage.getItem('idUser');

    return await axios({
      method: 'POST',
      url: this.urlWebservice,
      data: {
        tokenMobile: tokenMobile,
        keyConnect: keyConnect,
        methode: method,
        etat: state,
        login: login,
      },
    })
      .then((response) => {
          console.log(response)
        return response;
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        alert(err.toString());
        console.log( `première erreur ${err}`)
        return false;
      });
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param listeInit [username, password]
     * @returns {Promise<void>}
     */
     static async initDonneesAccueil(listeInit) {
      let username = listeInit[0];
      let password = listeInit[1];

    return await axios({
      method: 'POST',
      url: this.urlWebservice,
      data: {
        username: username,
        password: password,
        methode: 'initDonneesAccueil',
        etat: 'init',
      },
    })
      .then(response => {
          console.log(response)
        if (response.data.status) {
          AsyncStorage.setItem('tokenMobile', response.data.tokenmsg);
          AsyncStorage.setItem('keyConnect', response.data.keyconnect);
          AsyncStorage.setItem(
            'tokenTimestamp',
            (+new Date() + 3600000).toString(),
          );
          AsyncStorage.setItem(
            'initDonneesAccueil',
            JSON.stringify(response.data.resultat),
          );
          AsyncStorage.setItem('idUser', username);
          return true;
        } else {
          if (response.data.msgErreur) {
            alert(response.data.msgErreur);
          } else {
            alert(response.data);
          }
          return false;
        }
      })
      .catch(err => {
        alert(err.toString());
        console.log(`deuxième erreur ${err}`)
        return false;
      });
     }

     static async getLoginPwd(keyConnect: String): Array {}


     static async APIValidate(apiKey: Array): String {}

     static async KeyConnectValidate(apiKeyConnect: Array): String {}

     static async getTokenRequest(tokenKey: Array): String {}

     static async TokenValidate(token: Array): String {
      return this.request('TokenValidate', 'detail');
    }

    static async getTokenKeyConnect(tokenKeyConnect: Array): Array {}
    }
```

Comment: follow this https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28551

Comment: thank you for your time. Unfortunately none of these answer works on me i tryed everything...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i finally fixed my issue : Like it said in the link from @Nisharg Shah, first of all you need to have a react-native version 0.63.3 after make sure of your Flipper version and change it to 0.54.0. If like me it doesn't work just create a new project, the last version will be installed. My dependency "react native pdf" had an issue too "More than one file was found with OS independent path 'lib/x86/libjsc.so'" add in android/app/build.gradle file into android object this :

```
 packagingOptions {
    pickFirst 'lib/x86/libc++_shared.so'
    pickFirst 'lib/x86_64/libjsc.so'
    pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libjsc.so'
    pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so'
    pickFirst 'lib/x86_64/libc++_shared.so'
    pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so'
}
```

and everything should work fine :).